# Scripting language parser

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm making a scripting language parser and it's shaping up well but it takes about 30ms to do 30 or so odd/even checks.

`Profiler` tells me that it's taking most of the time in the `InvokeOperator.Operate` function but that doesn't tell me a lot because the Operate call the Run method on the `CodeBlock` which in turn again calls the Operate call and makes it very hard to actually determine what's taking as long.

Here's the [Github repo](https://github.com/LukaHorvat/Kento)

Here are the most important bits of the code:

```
Stack<Token> solvingStack = new Stack<Token>();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < value.Count ; ++i )
{
   if ( value[ i ] is Operator )
   {
      Operator op = (Operator)value[ i ];
      if ( op.Type == OperatorType.PrefixUnary || op.Type == OperatorType.SufixUnary )
      {
         op.Operate( ( solvingStack.Pop() as Value ), new NoValue() );
      } else
      {
         Value second = (Value)solvingStack.Pop();
         Value result = op.Operate( ( solvingStack.Pop() as Value ), second );
         solvingStack.Push( result );
      }
   } else
   {
      solvingStack.Push( value[ i ] );
   }
}
Compiler.ExitScope();
if ( solvingStack.Count == 0 ) return new NoValue();
else return (Value)solvingStack.Peek();
```

It's how the code is parsed after the infix expression is turned into RPN.
A token can be an operator or a value and a value can be a literal, identifier, `codeblock`.

A somewhat special case is a function because it's not parsed to RPN directly but only the code inside of it is. Then is there's an invoke operator, it takes the array of arguments that was provided and the function before it and runs the function (which inherits from `CodeBlock`, so it also runs the same thing that is shown here).

What each operator does on different types of values is determined by the operator itself in the Operators.cs file.

Comment: see `Make sure you include your code in your question` part in [FAQ](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: As @Snowbear points out, we do require questions to contain the relevant code inside the post. If you can edit your post to contain the most important parts of the code and a summary of the ones you left out, so that the code can be meaningfully reviewed based on the code in the question, please do so. If that's not possible, I'm afraid this question is not appropriate here.

Comment: Is this the InvokeOperator.Operate method?

Comment: @Michael, no, it's `CodeBlock.Run()` method

Comment: `30 ms` doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: Could you post how you wrote the odd/even checks?

Comment: Well, there's a function that mods the number it gets by 2 and checks the result. Nothing complicated really.

Comment: @Darwin, replace it with `(num & 1) == 1`, it should be faster

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if these are bottlenecks, but they are at least performance improvements.

1. Replace `Stack<Token>` with `Stack<Value>` since you are only pushing/popping `Value`. This way there is no need to do expensive casts.
2. You can replace

   ```
   if ( value[ i ] is Operator )
   {
       Operator op = (Operator)value[ i ];
   ```

   with

   ```
   Operator op = value[ i ] as Operator;
   if ( op != null ) // it was an Operator
   ```

   to have only one typecheck (`x as y`) instead of two (`x is y` and `(y) x`).
3. You can replace

   ```
   for ( int i = 0 ; i < value.Count ; ++i )
   ```

   with

   ```
   foreach(Token item in value)
   ```

   to eliminate the index operations `value[ i ]`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try using a profiler of some sort in order to determine exactly where the bottleneck is. Once you do that, it will much easier to find how to avoid it.

Comment: Profiler tells me that it's taking most of the time in the InvokeOperator.Operate function but that doesn't tell me a lot because the Operate call the Run method on the CodeBlock which in turn again calls the Operate call and makes it very hard to actually determine what's taking as long.

Comment: What you need to do is profile the function calls inside the operate call, then figure out which one exactly is taking so long. Then go into that and do the same thing.